# JSON parse and retrieve string

Tags: c#, json.net, downloadstring

I am trying to get the element to print the `browser_download_url` from the JSON of https://api.github.com/repos/MyBotRun/MyBot/releases/latest

It will not print the  browser_download_url

```
public class Asset
{
 public string browser_download_url { get; set; }
}


wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36Accept");             
var json = wc.DownloadString(@"https://api.github.com/repos/MyBotRun/MyBot/releases/latest");
if (json.Contains("browser_download_url"))
{
  Asset asset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asset>(json);
  Console.WriteLine(asset.browser_download_url);
}
```

Comment: `Assets` is an `array` in your json. So you got to deserialize accordingly

Comment: what does it print instead? are there any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON in the URL that you link does not match the `Asset` class that you are trying to deserialize to.

I would recommend using a tool like [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io?share=sjhSHvB1EZctL0bPDDF7) and paste your JSON in there and it will generate the C# classes for you.

After copying that example class you could then use the following code:

```
var asset = Asset.FromJson(json);

Console.WriteLine(asset.AssetElement[0].BrowserDownloadUrl);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, rather a suggestion, so please leave the same as a comment

Comment: There will be no upvote here, please consider showing a concrete answer or pasting this as a comment

Comment: As requested, I have added an example

Comment: Your example is wrong. This will result in a compiler error.

Comment: +1 vote for a informing us of a cool tool out there that converts json to a c# class. That's pretty neat.